# Add and get reply item from message discussion board

Tags: sharepoint-online, asp.net, soap

I want to add reply in particular subject in message discussion bord type list  and get reply of subject from message discussion bord type list by SOAP services.

I am using SOAP services of SharePoint.

How to add item and get item from message discussion board?

Which type of SOAP service use for that?

Comment: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/post-and-reply-on-sharepoint-2010-discussion-board.html

Comment: @Kapil Which SOAP service use to get particular replay from message discussion board?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e106d98c-cf90-4ae4-be5e-3217a4a44b76/message-reply-and-discussion-assocation-in-discussion-board?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Comment: Just following up on this, was almost a year ago, did you get somewhere with this?

Comment: @Yugo Still not get any solution